# Installing python3 python3-pip and awscli on elasticsearch_exporter container

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, containers

I am trying to install following packages on elasticsearch_exporter container.
I tried yuminstall and apt-get and could not install using them.
Can someone tell how to install packages on this container?

**Linux elasticsearch-exporter-6dbd9cf659-7km8x 5.2.9-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Aug 16 08:17:55 EDT 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux**

Error:
apt-get install python3
sh: apt-get: not found

python3
python3-pip
awscli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to `justwatch/elasticsearch_exporter` image, then it is based on `busybox` image ([source](https://github.com/prometheus-community/elasticsearch_exporter/blob/master/Dockerfile#L3)). There is no package manager inside and adding one would be rather difficult.

An easy way to solve this is to just copy the exporter into regular Debian image, like this:

```
FROM justwatch/elasticsearch_exporter:1.1.0 as source

FROM debian:buster-slim
COPY --from=source /bin/elasticsearch_exporter /bin/elasticsearch_exporter

EXPOSE      9114
ENTRYPOINT  [ "/bin/elasticsearch_exporter" ]
```

And here is your exporter with `apt` inside.